# what is the equivalent of an if-statement in ARM?

Tags: input, architecture, arm, division, multiplication

So, I am working on a program in ARM that takes a bunch of numbers from a file and tells if they are even or odd.

The problem is that I know how to multiply by 0.5, but I don't know how to do something like this high level statement in ARM

```
if (A / 2 == 0)
    print even
else
    print odd
```

Here's what I have in terms of code:

```
@open input file
ldr r0,=FileName        @ set Name for input file
mov r1,#0                 @ mode is input
swi SWI_Open              @ open file for input
bcs InFileError           @ if error?
ldr r1,=InFileHandle      @ load input file handle
str r0,[r1]               @ save the file handle

@read integers from input file
NUMBERS:
ldr r0,=InputFileHandle   @ load input file handle
ldr r0,[r0]
swi SWI_RdInt             @ read the integer into R0
bcs EofReached       @ Check Carry-Bit (C): if= 1 then EOF reached

@multiplication by 0.5 to test for odd or even
MUL R2 R0 0.5
@what is the test in ARM
@for ( R0 / 0.5 ) == a multiple of 1?

B NUMBERS
LOOP:

@end of program
Message1: .asciz"Hello World!"
EOL:     .asciz   "\n"
NewL:    .ascii   "\n"
Blank:   .ascii   " "
FileName: .asciz"input.txt"
.end
```

So I think the first two things inputting from the file and reading the integers works. I don't know how to test for the condition that it is divisible by 2. I think it's multiplied by 0.5 and then the next step is to say even if that number doesn't have a decimal place with anything after it at the end, but if it does then then number A that was divided into number B is odd. Otherwise it is even?

Answer (score 0):

A brief answer: you don't need to multiply by 0.5 or anything like that. You need to check the value of LSB (least significant bit) of the value. It will be 0 for even numbers and 1 for odd numbers.

Upd.: your "C" code is also wrong. You want to use A % 2, not A / 2

Comment: Thanks. I know what in programming, I just forgot because its been a while. I know % is the modulo operator. I just was really tired when I typed that.

Comment: Can you send me a link to an article that says how to check the value of LSB? I want to know what I'm doing. Could you provide an example?

Comment: There's no article, it's an elementary operation. If you're learning ARM asm you have the ARM Reference Manual, don't you? If not - google for it and download, it is a must to have. Look at TST instruction, or ANDS R0,R0,#1 - will do the same job but will destroy the content of R0.. (PS: You can edit your question to correct your mistakes too).